# Add class after return (or map) Javascript + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to add a class after returning a map, basically im trying to highlight the text after translating each word im doing it by adding a  CSS class to it. I'm able to add the class but just to the whole box instead of the words i changed, i've tried many methods but i guess im not understanding well the functions, i've tried matchAll, also tried replacing them as the previous method, and tried styling them directly but im still unable to achieve it, i've also tried adding the function right after the "return" but javascript ends the execution of the function when return is called.... :/

Thanks for your time!

```
 export default function Text() {

    var inputText;
    var mapObj = { blue: "azul", green: "verde", yellow: "amarillo" };
    
    function changeText() {
      inputText = document.querySelector("#inputF");
      document.getElementById("outputF").innerHTML = inputText.value.replaceAll(/\b(blue|green|yellow)\b(|,.$)/gi,
      function(matched){
      return mapObj[matched];
    })
    outputF.classList.add("mark");
    }
return (
    <div>
          <textarea id="inputF"></textarea>
          <button onClick={changeText}>Change</button>
          <textarea id="outputF"></textarea>   
    </div>
  );
};



///CSS

.mark{
  background-color:blue;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using more React here instead of native JS especially for the state management of this component I may have gone a bit over board, but I updated your component to the following:

```
const Text = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState('');
  const [output, setOutput] = React.useState('');
  const mapObj = {
    blue: "azul", 
    green: "verde", 
    yellow: "amarillo" 
  };
    
  const changeText = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const changedText = input.replaceAll(
      /\b(blue|green|yellow)\b(|,.$)/gi,
      (matched) => `<span class="mark">${mapObj[matched]}</span>`
    )
    setOutput(changedText);
  }
  return (
    <form>
      <textarea 
        id="inputF" 
        value={input} 
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={changeText}>Change</button> 
      <div 
        id="outputF"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: output}}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3tc2xzms/

For starters, I added 2 `useState` hooks to manage the input and output text. And then for the highlight portion, each matched word that was changed gets wrapped in a `span.mark`. Also the output textarea was changed to a div.

Related Docs:

- Forms: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
- State Hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
- Setting string as HTML: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much segFault <3! Definitely i should dig deeper in hooks and states on React,  and also its a better option because they text gets saved on the local memory of the users.

Answer (score 0):

The style you applied will change the background color of whole `textarea`, what you can do instead is use `setSelectionRange()` method of textarea, that will give you the result near to what you are expecting.

```
    function changeText() {
      inputText = document.querySelector("#inputF");
      document.getElementById("outputF").innerHTML = inputText.value.replaceAll(/\b(blue|green|yellow)\b(|,.$)/gi,
      function(matched){
      return mapObj[matched];
    })
    // something like this
    // here you need to set start and end index for the highlights part, you can use the logic as per need
    outputF.setSelectionRange(0, inputText.value.length )
    }
```

and to change the highlight color you can use the following css:

```
::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Hi Arslan! thanks for your feedback, i tried your answer and still is not working, basically what i want to do is just highlight the words that i changed not every word on the textbox